# how to concatenate symbol/icon with String for bar chart's labels using dc.js

Tags: dc.js

```
 rowChart
    .width(500)
    .height(200)
    .dimension(neighborhoodDimension)
    .group(neighborhoodGroup)
    .label(function (d) { return d.value;})
```

[image: Sample label for bar chart]

I wanted to concatenate symbol/icon with bar chart's label something like screen shots. Working example in JsFiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/3chM6/460/

Comment: The only labels provided by dc.js bar charts are above the bars, and there's nothing built-in to display those symbols (or even multi-line labels). So you'll have to draw these bits yourself, probably in response to the `pretransition` event.

Comment: Thanks Gordan, i will try to draw these icons by pretransition. But, can i pass Unicode for icon/symbol concatenate with string in the label's method.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to add a symbol to the single-line label that is supported by dc.js, you can do it by supplying a custom `.label()` function. [As noted in the comments, multi-line labels and labels to the sides of bars would need some custom `pretransition` code.]

The default label for bar charts is the obscure

```
_chart.label(function (d) {
    return dc.utils.printSingleValue(d.y0 + d.y);
}, false);
```

[(source link)](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/2fa1fca11d30a3ac170cedb9661aa7e21fc6326e/src/bar-chart.js#L55-L57)

It is this way because bar charts are stacked, so this finds the total up to the  stack. Labels are only shown for the top stack.

The bar chart labels use `selection.text()` to specify the content:

```
        .text(function (d) {
            return _chart.label()(d);
        });
```

[(source link)](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/2fa1fca11d30a3ac170cedb9661aa7e21fc6326e/src/bar-chart.js#L131-L133)

Since that's `.text()` and not `.html()`, this means you can't use HTML character entities. But you can still add a Unicode symbol by typing the symbol directly into your UTF8 source:

```
          .label(d => d.y0 + d.y + '⯅');
```

I got this one on Linux by typing <kbd>leftctrl-shift-U</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> - other operating systems have different ways of typing directly in UTF8.

Result:

[image: arrow labels]

You could add some logic to this to choose different symbols, but that's about as far as you can go with the built-in functionality. You won't be able to have the color different from the text, and they can only go on top of the bars.

Adding custom labels with custom placement, multiple lines, multiple colors, isn't too hard but I don't have time to work up an example right now. Search for [dc.js] pretransition or renderlet and you should dig up some examples here on SO.

Comment: Hmm, I see that this symbol doesn't exist in very many fonts. I just lucked out on Linux and its Liberation Mono and Liberation Sans fonts. Symbols like 0x2b06 ⬆ 0x2b07 ⬇ seem to be more common.